# how to get value of cell in table and display it in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>789</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="txtDsCode" id="txtDsCode"/>
</form>
```

When I click on the `textbox` and then click on the `cell` in the table , the value of the cell will display in the `textbox`.
How should i do it with javascript?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `querySelectorAll` to select `td` elements
- Use `Array.from` to cast `array-like-object` to `array` to apply `array` method
- Register events using `addEventListener`

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable td');
Array.from(cells).forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('txtDsCode').value = this.textContent;
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>789</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="txtDsCode" id="txtDsCode" />
</form>
```